# Error 13 Permission denied

Tags: python

Помогите разобраться . Имеется программа написанная на питоне и конвертированная в exe  с помощью auto-py-to-exe под Windows. В числе прочего, одной из ее функций является создание файла и запись в него некоторых  данных. Если ее запустить как обычный пользователь мышкой, то все работает. Но мне нужно что бы она запускалась автоматически при старте системы. И вот как раз при старте работает все кроме записи на диск(файл не создается и нет записи в него). Вывод программы показывает ошибку Error 13 Permission denied.При этом если отключить ее и опять перезапустить в ручную - все работает .Пробовал записывает ее в разные ветки реестра и в HKLM и в HKCU - не работает все равно. В чем может быть проблема?
P.S.
Владелец файла-администратор с полными правами доступа

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Или файл занят другим процессом и/или нужно программу под админа запускать. Кст, непонятно на что нет прав, у вам там и работа с файлами, и с реестром. Лучше приложите минимальный пример, чтобы не было неоднозначности

Comment: от чьего имени запускается программа при автозапуске? можно посмотреть в таск-менеджере в закладке "процессы"

Comment: В обоих случаях (HKLM и HKCU) программа висит в процессах от имени текущего пользователя

Answer (score 1):

Если программа запускается как служба или через планировщик заданий, то можно указать пользователя, от имени которого происходит запуск.

Другой вариант - дать тому пользователю, от которого запускается программа права на запись нужной папки.

И ещё, не надо писать файл в корень диска.

Comment: пользователь, от которого запускается программа, имеет права на запись и программа не в корне,а в домашней папке этого пользователя

Comment: Не программа в корне, а запись куда?

Comment: В ту же папку где и программа,  в домашнюю пользователя